# PHP Utf8 MySQL_Querying, JSON_Encoding

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a MySQL DB, encoded in UTF8, where some records have 'ā's in them (in case it doesn't show up right in SO, that's an 'a' with a line above it).

There is a PHP script that is getting the records, putting them in an array, and json_encoding them. No matter whether the script is being invoked by ajax or the webpage, the 'ā's show up as question marks. Where is the problem, and how do I fix it?

Thanks,
Jamie McClymont

EDIT: Forgot to mention that the 'ā's show up fine in PHPMyAdmin

Comment: You should try 3 steps: 
1.Your meta tag in html page (charset="UTF-8")
2. set client charset mysql_set_charset('utf-8',$link); check out this page [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php)
3. Run sql statement: SET NAMES 'UTF8'

Give it a try ^^

Comment: I use that, but I don't believe that that's the problem. The PHP script is returning JSON data, no HTML

Comment: How about Character Encoding of your browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the text to print correctly you need to set the charset of the mysql connection and the page

For the connection the following query will work

```
set names utf8
```

Run this query right after connecting

If the charset is still incorrect try adding

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

assuming you're outputting json

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html